# Lubuntu (LXDE) and Dolphin filemanager

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, dolphin

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10. I'm really satisfied with LXDE except for the file manager PCManFM which not enough features. So I've decided to switch to dolphin which I've downloaded using synaptic. The thing now is: the only way to start dolphin is by typing its name into the terminal even though there's a (not responding) shortcut in the panel.

Any ideas??

Got the same issue with Gnome and Konqueror if that helps...

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Got it to work!!!

Seems like I had to set Dolphin as the default file manager under 'lxsession-default-apps'. You can find it under preferences--->Default applications for LXSession.

Just replace 'PCManFM' with 'Dophin' and you should be good to go.

Good luck!!!

Comment: It does not work for me. I navigated to `lxsession-default-apps` -> `Running applications` -> `File Manager` and I set: Command: dolphin, Session: Lubuntu, Extras: none. I also restarted the OS, but folders from desktop and panel plugin are still opened by PCManFM.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that didn't work for me in lubuntu 13.10.  Am I missing something simple here?

If I don't get a fix for this I'm going back to kubuntu.  I'm willing to forgive lubuntu a few rough edges for the speed but only so many ...

Comment: sorry for the late reply. you should also restart you machine after setting your default apps in lubuntu.